# How to prevent UIView background from rotating?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I rotate a UIView without the black bars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037924/can-i-rotate-a-uiview-without-the-black-bars)

I want the labels on my `UIView` to rotate (and they do) but I've set the `background` to a color other than black.  When I rotate you can see the view's rectangle rotate against a black `background`.  How can I keep the `UIView`'s `background` still yet allow the rest of the `subviews` to rotate normally?  And what is that black `background` behind everything?  Do I have access to it?

Comment: Could you post some code? We will help you much faster

Comment: This is a pretty generic implementation, in fact a vanilla 'Single View Application' when rotated will show the default white background rotate above a black background.  I want to prevent the black background from being seen.

Comment: I don't think you can do much about that.

Comment: I think you may be right, although I wouldn't call the visible background areas black bars.  More like triangles.  This and the response from Mattia should set me on the right track.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question. What I think your question is (if I'm misunderstanding please clarify where I'm getting the question wrong):

- You have a UIView that is the same size as the device's screen.
- You want to rotate that view.
- When you rotate that view the background of the view's parent view can be seen.

I think the only ways to resolve this are either:

A) Make the view you're rotating larger than the screen so that when you rotate the parent view isn't visible. If you do this make sure the parent view isn't set to clip it's subviews otherwise you won't see any difference after resizing.

OR

B) Make the parent view's background color match the color of the view you're rotating. If you don't want to permanently alter the background color of the parent view you can always change the color when you start the animation and revert to the original color when done.

P.S. - I think the "black background behind everything" is the background color of your app's UIWindow. If you want to change that you can do the following (assuming your app delegate has a window property defined but if you used one of the standard Xcode templates to create your app it should):

```
UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window];
[window setBackgroundColor:<Some UIColor>];
```