# Is it possible to change background color of interface rotation

Tags: ios, uikit

My App has a white background `UIWindow.backgroundcolor`. When I rotate the device the white background rotates on black background.
Is it possible to change the background behind that window?

I would like to have all white. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your question is similar to this one...you can check out my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037924/can-i-rotate-a-uiview-without-the-black-bars/43896578#43896578

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the black color as it is actually not a part of the app. What you can do in this case is add a very large (somewhat larger then the screen size) root view and center it. Then place everything else into this view. This way when your app changes orientation the large view will also rotate, but because of it's size it's edges will never reach the screen and the black color will remain hidden.